# Error when read data from oracle with spark

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark, jdbc

There is a field of type `NUMBER(2,3)` in the table (in oracle database).

When I read this table with spark, the following exception occurs:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
    Decimal scale (3) cannot be greater than precision (2).
```

How can I solve this problem?

The code I am reading the table data is as follows:

```
val df = spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@**:1521:**")
    .option("user", "**")
    .option("password", "**")
    .option("dbtable", "table_name")
    .load()
```